# Manipulate PHP file with PHP

Tags: php, html, save

I want to replace specific strings in a php file by calling a function.
All i got till now is:

```
function change_data($data1, $data2)
{
    //Read php file in $result
    $result= str_replace("tag1", $data1, $result);
    $result= str_replace("tag2", $data2, $result);
    //Save php file
}
```

Can you help me and is it save so no one else can access the file?

Edit: I tried the following:

```
function change_data($data1, $data2)
{
    $file = 'test.php';
$result = file_get_contents($file);
    //Replace initial with test
$result = str_replace("intial", "test", $result);

file_put_contents($file, $result);
}
```

Nothing changes in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the functions [`file_get_contents()`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.file-get-contents.php) for reading and [`file_put_contents()`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.file-put-contents.php) for writing files from and to the file system.

Comment: This does not seem to work for me, I edited my question to show what i did

Answer (score 0):

it save so no one else can access the file?

This can be a very effective way to protect your directory. Any other directory in public_html can be protected in the same way. This method only works if you have a static IP address assigned to you. Anyone attempting to browse such directories using a different IP Address will get a 403 Forbidden error.

1. In the directory you wish to protect, open (or create) a file called, .htaccess. (Note the dot at the beginning of the file name.)
2. Add the following code to this file, replacing 100.100.100.100 in this example with the static IP address you plan to allow:

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 100.100.100.100

Answer (score -1):

```
function change_data($data1, $data2)
{
    $file = 'change_this_with_filename';
    $result = file_get_contents($file);

    $result = str_replace(array("tag1", "tag2"), array($data1, $data2), $result);

    file_put_contents($file, $result);
}
```